# Eclipse plugin to find the error on Double Click the file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I need the help in console view of eclipse. When i build my project all my errors and warnings are displayed in console window and if i need to find the place where it showing those errors i need have to go into that file and find those information. I feel its much iritating to find when errors are huge. So is there any plugin available that take us to that location of errors on double click. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to left click on the warning or error once, to make sure that the Eclipse Problems view has focus.  Then, you double click on the warning or error description, and the cursor will take you to the warning or error in your code.